# css issue that I am struggling with?

Tags: jquery, css

If you see My JSFiddler http://jsfiddle.net/7mfj7/2/. First time "Change Picture" directly showing on image. If I mouse over on image and come out from image.  then it is working fine.

How to hide "Change Picture" first time and display on mouse over?

Comment: use this fiddle instead http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/7mfj7/4/

Comment: @3nigma: The text still showing in the begging. I dont want that way. Hover time only need to diplay

Comment: it was not an answer i edited your fiddle only for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this at the top of your `$(function () {` :

`$('.comment').css({ "top": '400px' });`

http://jsfiddle.net/7mfj7/10/

Comment: It'd probably be better to do this with actual CSS instead of waiting for the Javascript to do it.

Comment: But if the user has JS disabled, the link will permanently sit 400px below the top of the screen.  This way, if the user has JS disabled, the links show and behave normally.  It all depends on what the OP needs.

Comment: Good point. It comes down to whether you're ok with having the link "blink" with Javascript enabled. If you really wanted to get fancy, you could probably use the :hover pseudo-selector to imitate that functionality without any Javascript at all (although it wouldn't be animated, and IE6/7 would still have compatibility issues).

Comment: And if you were really picky about the "blink", you could place the javascript directly below the HTML elements it acts on, and remove the `$(document).ready( )` call, acting on the elements immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Add the style to the css

```
.comment{
  top: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS for `.comment`:

```
top: 400px;
```

That way it will load initially in the same place it gets moved to on mouseout.

Answer (score 0):

Set it initially to `display: none;` if you do not want it to show when you first enter the page.

Then on your hover command, set it to `.show()`

http://jsfiddle.net/7mfj7/18/

Answer (score 0):

Rather then using child and parent to reference elements inside the jquery call. it will be easier to wrap each elements in it's own div . (i.e. the text in one div and the image in another) this will allows you to control the individual elements more specifically in the jquery and also apply styles easier.